# Calling python scripts into from JAVA(with parameters) and returning back the results to JAVA

Tags: java, python, java-native-interface, anaconda, jython

I have solved this problem using Runtime. It's like triggering the .py file in cmd and passing cmd line arguments and finally reading back the results from the console (the print values) using Buffered reader and Input stream.
It's awfully slow. Is there a better method to do this? I'm using Anaconda 4.1.1 Python 2.7... 
If I use Jython but how do I use  conda packages like pandas, Jason, pyodbc etc... Or how do I resolve these packages...I know the anaconda creates a virtual environment which might be an issue with this...
I have gone through some the answers... I can run simple programs with those....But how do I use libraries like scipy,numpy,pandas,json...Etc..

Comment: You should show code. We currently have no idea exactly how you are trying to do this.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/mkopsnc/keplerhacks/tree/master/python in this sample, Python is called via JNI. Inside wrapper code (JNI methods) you can deal with Python objects. This is not exactly what you are looking for, but it may help.